# C# - Receive string and use it as an enum key

Tags: c#, string, web, service, enums

**EDIT:** I've been working with C# for Two days, I'm web developer and I come from PHP, I would need some detail explanation

I'm consuming a Currency convertor Web service. The web service namespace contain an enum structure with the currencies:

```
public enum Currency {
    /// <remarks/>
    AFA,
    /// <remarks/>
    ALL,
    /// <remarks/>
    DZD,
    /// <remarks/>
    ARS,
    /// <remarks/>
    AWG,
    /// <remarks/>
    AUD,
    /// <remarks/>
    BSD,
    /// <remarks/>
    BHD
    //... AND SO ON
}
```

The method I use to get the Conversion Rate is (with example):

```
// ---
// --- Variable type is the enum
// ---
ConvertorReference.Currency from;
ConvertorReference.Currency to;

ConvertorReference.CurrencyConvertorSoapClient service = new ConvertorReference.CurrencyConvertorSoapClient();

// --
// -- Here I asign one of the enum keys
// --
from = ConvertorReference.Currency.USD;
to = ConvertorReference.Currency.COP;


rate = service.ConversionRate(from, to);

Console.Write("1 USD is $" + rate + " Colombia Pesos");
//Outputs: 1 USD is $2380.88 Colombian Pesos
```

I would like to ask the user for a string, where he can insert for example `"USD"` or `"COP"`.

After receiving that string I want to know if it is possible to use something like.

```
curr = Console.ReadLine("Insert the currency you want to perform the operation: ");
```

Now the variable `curr` would be something like "USD";

Can I do something like this to get the same result?:

```
from = ConvertorReference.Currency.curr;
```

Comment: If I've misread your question, and the above link doesn't ask/answer the same thing you're asking, can you explain more the difference of your question?

Comment: I don't understand some C# code they put there. I'm new to C#... I would need comments so I can know what's happening. I apologize

Comment: The simple answer is use Enum.TryParse. For example, `Currency curr; if (Enum.TryParse("AFA", out curr)) { //success } else { //failed to convert};`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499%28v=vs.110%29.aspx